# {birthday} is not showing

Tags: members, solspace-user

I'm using Solspace's User add-on and I want to show a simple list of all registered members:

```
{exp:user:users group_id="5"}
<tr>
    <td>{screen_name}</td>
    <td>{email}</td>
    <td>{birthday}</td>
</tr>
{/exp:user:users}
```

However, the birthday just prints {birthday} as if the tag isn't recognized. The other two print just fine.

I have no clue as to what causes this. Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a variable is returned, instead of echoing out your data means that it isn't an associated variable.

In the [Solspace User docs](http://www.solspace.com/docs/), it uses the variable {bday_d}. Try that, but there are more for the birthday, so check them out.

Comment: Thanks! At first I couldn't find it in the docs, now I have: [Solspace User: Stats (Profile)](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/stats/)